# Faster/Easier query for this result-array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, left-join

I'm trying to get an array that contains information from three tables. The result should be an array where I can loop through the first table, its related rows from the second and again the related rows from the third to the second. At the moment, I'm having three separate SQL queries, that then get reformed into one single array.

Maybe someone can help me with an idea of the best way to query those tables to get the array below. I currently got three queries - one for each table. With the mysql JOIN it's quite an easy query, but I'm having problems with arranging it back to the array.

I'm thinking of using a mysql JOIN to get the same result with less queries, but actually I'm wondering whether that's so good or even possible at all. I'll add numbers to the approximate sizes of the tables.

Let me give you some details:

**THE TABLES**

```
courses(4000 rows)
course_id----course_date

groups(50 000 rows)
group_id----group_size----group_course_id

users(200 000 rows)
user_id----user_name----user_group_id
```

An example of the desired array:

```
[0] => Array('courseinfo' => 
              Array('course_id' => 1234,
                    'course_date' => '2012-08-12')
             'groups' =>
              Array( [0] => Array('group_id' => 345,
                                  'group_size' => 3,
                                  'group_course_id' => 1234,
                                  'users' => Array([0] => Array('user_id' => 456,'user_name' => Pete Cabrinha, 'user_group_id = '345'), 
                                                   [1] => Array('user_id' => 336,'user_name' => John Smith, 'user_group_id = '345'))
                     [1] => Array('group_id' => 345,
                                  'group_size' => 3,
                                  'group_course_id' => 1234,
                                   'users' => Array([0] => Array('user_id' => 456,'user_name' => Pete Cabrinha, 'user_group_id = '1234'), 
                                                    [1] => Array('user_id' => 336,'user_name' => John Smith, 'user_group_id = '1234'))))
```

Hope it's not too complicated, just note the relation between the course_id AND group_course_id as well as the relation between group_id and user_group_id.

Heres a little snippet of the way I query at the moment:

```
    $data = $courses = $read->read_courses();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($courses as $course)
    {
        if($data[$i]['groups'] = $read->read_groups($course['course_id']))
        {
            $j = 0;
            foreach($data[$i]['groups'] as $group)
            {
                $data[$i]['groups'][$j]['users'] = $read->read_users($group['group_id']);
                $j++;
            }
        }
        else {$data[$i]['groups'][0] = array(); $data[$i]['groups'][0]['users'] = array();}
        $i++;
    }
```

And finally the JOIN I thought of using...

```
        SELECT 
            course.course_id,
            course.course_date,

            groups.group_id,
            groups.group_course_id,
            groups.group_size,

            user.user_name


        FROM course
        LEFT JOIN groups 
        ON course.course_id = groups.group_course_id

        LEFT JOIN user
        ON groups.group_id = user.user_group
```

Hope someone can help me here, or put me in the right direction - or even come up with a way better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that query as you can see in the answer, but you should never load the whole database in a PHP array. According to your comment, you need one month at a time, so add a WHERE clause to limit the results to the month you want.

For instance:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= date_col;
```

This will give you the last 30 days.

Alternatively, you can display only a certain number of records at a time using LIMIT:

```
LIMIT 0, 100
```

will give you 100 records starting at offset 0 (the first 100 records). It makes it easier to paginate.

If you want to get the newest courses first, you use ORDER BY:

```
ORDER BY course.course_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 100
```

Then you only need to change the limit on each query to get the next batch of records to display and of course, your queries will be very fast and use little memory because you never download more than 100 records.

---

Sorry, but it sounds like you are doing the database's work in PHP.

Why on Earth would you load 254k entries in a PHP array? You are NOT going to display 254k records on a single page, are you? The performance would be horrendous and just a handful of users will crash your server.

You should really re-think what data you really need and how you will use it.

What are you trying to do? What data do you need? How can you get it from the database server?

Comment: Actually I just want to display all the bookings for a course for the whole year at once. I would always limit the amount to one month and then re-query facebook-timeline-style.

Comment: @DanSurfrider In that case, you should absolutely limit the records you query to one month at a time. See answer edit.

Answer (score 0):

Rather use this

```
    SELECT *
    FROM bs_course course 

    LEFT JOIN bs_group AS groups 
    ON course.course_id = groups.group_course_id

    LEFT JOIN bs_user AS user 
    ON groups.group_id = user.user_group_id

    ORDER BY course.course_date,course.course_lock,course.course_name,groups.group_status,groups.group_created
```

Then go for the loop. `group_course_id` and `user_group_id` is to be used in the ON condition.

this will give you the result but still you have to create a loop for the required result.

Wait for my reply for the loop to use to create the above array.

**EDIT:**

Use this function to create the array:

```
function create_array($resultset){
    if(!$resultset){return NULL;}

    $current_cid=0;
    $current_cid_counter = 0;
    $current_gid=0;
    $current_gid_counter = 0;
    $current_uid_counter = 0;
    $return_array = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)){
        if($current_cid!=$row['course_id']){
            $return_array[$current_cid_counter++]['courseinfo'] = array('course_id'=>$row['course_id'],'course_date'=>$row['course_date']);
            $current_cid = $row['course_id'];
            $current_gid_counter = 0;
            $current_uid_counter = 0;
        }
        if($current_gid!=$row['group_id']){
            $return_array[$current_cid_counter-1]['groups'][$current_gid_counter++] = array('group_id' => $row['group_id'],'group_size' => $row['group_size'],'group_course_id' => $row['course_id']);
            $current_gid = $row['group_id'];
            $current_uid_counter = 0;
        }
        $return_array[$current_cid_counter-1]['groups'][$current_gid_counter-1]['users'][$current_uid_counter++] = array('user_id' => $row['user_id'],'user_name' => $row['user_name'], 'user_group_id' => $row['group_id']);
    }

    return $return_array;
}
```

I m using mysql extension, if you use any other extension then edit it accordingly

Comment: In my example I only had a few columns, but in reality there are way more columns in the db, so it's quite unsatisfying that I have to add them all so complicated in the query..no better idea?

Comment: you want only 3 level penetration of an array. only this code can give you such an array. SQL query wont help you out. and no matter how many rows you have in the db, no other fast solution can be found. And on the server, they are way faster than normal systems in processing. but tell me that you are not going to fetch and show all the data on same page!!! You better put pagination or something of this. Well a series of select box will help you out.